# Passing xmlFile path as a parameter with maven cmd to surefire plugin on -mvn test

Tags: java, maven, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm trying to pass the xml file path through command line on maven project, and nothing seems to work. I almost always get *"Unknown lifecycle phase ".xml".* error for every solution I found so far online.

This is how my plugin looks like:

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>${smoke}</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

First of all, I wasn't able to save it if I didn't set it as a property of pom.xml, so I did it and hardcoded the path to my xml and it works. However, I can't seem to find a way to change that value while running mvn clean test ...

I tried things like these:

```
mvn clean test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFile=smokeSuite.xml`
mvn clean test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFile=src/test/smokeSuite.xml
mvn clean test -DsuiteXmlFile=smokeSuite.xml
mvn clean test -Dsurefire.smoke=smokeSuite.xml`
mvn clean test -Dsurefire.smoke=src/test/smokeSuite.xml
mvn clean test -Dsmoke=smokeSuite.xml
```

Almost always I get the error that .xml is an unknown lyfecycle phase, or when I add a space after suiteXmlFile, like this,

```
mvn clean test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFile =src/test/smokeSuite.xml
```

I get that = is not a lyfecycle phase...

There's obviously something wrong with the command in the first place, but I cannot seem to find any documentation on how should the suiteXmlFile be passed down with mvn test ...

Comment: `mvn clean test -Dsmoke=smokeSuite.xml` should be the right way, but make sure the path is correct (relative to current dir)

Comment: @Randommm
I checked and the path is correct, but when I use that command I get an error saying  Unknown lifecycle phase ".xml". 
I know the path is correct because when I use
mvn clean test -Dsmoke=src/test/smokeSuite (without .xml) I get the error that the suite file is not a valid file... but at least it's showing the path and it's correct.
So it looks like every time I add .xml I get this error about the lifecycle phase

Comment: Have you tried with quotes?

Comment: @Randommm It works .. hahaha, I don't get why no one is using the quotes in all of the similar questions, and why it didn't occur to me to try it. Thank you a lot! Now I can create a proper Readme file finally. If you want you can post it as an answer as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you set it up as `<suiteXmlFile>${smoke}</suiteXmlFile>` you need to pass the variable with `-Dsmoke` and to make sure the value is parsed correctly you should wrap it in quotes to prevent it from being wrongly interpreted. So the full command should be

```
mvn clean test -Dsmoke="src/test/smokeSuite.xml"
```